# Using purrr to calculate recall over cross validated sets in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I saw a question recently so using iris to produce similar binary dataframe, I am trying to do 5 fold cross validation & then run recall over each cross validated set, everything runs perfectly except my last line which I am not sure why is giving me an error. Using iris dataset to show my data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rsample)

iris_b <-iris %>% 
     mutate(Species=as.character(Species),
        Species=case_when(Species=="setosa"~"versicolor",
                          TRUE~Species))
    
iris_b$Species <- as.factor(iris_b$Species) #new line added

bank_split <- initial_split (iris_b, prop = 0.70)
training_data <- training(bank_split)
testing_data <- testing(bank_split)

cv_split <- vfold_cv(training_data, v=5)

cv_data <- cv_split %>%
  mutate(train=map(splits,~training(.x)),
         validate=map(splits,~testing(.x)))

cv_models_bank <- cv_data %>%
  mutate(model=map(train,~glm(Species~.,data=.x,
                              family="binomial")))

cv_bank_prep  <- cv_models_bank %>%
  mutate(validate_actual=map(validate,~.x$Species=="virginica"),
         validate_predicted=map2(model,validate,
                                 ~predict(.x,.y,type="response")>0.5)) 

cv_perf_recall <- cv_bank_prep %>%
  mutate(validate_recall= map2(validate_actual,validate_predicted,~recall(.x,.y)))
```

I receive an error when trying to calculate recall using map2 in R, not sure, have tried to debug multiple times, but there is some error somewhere basic.

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `validate_recall`.
> x input data must be a factor
> i Input `validate_recall` is `map2(validate_actual, validate_predicted, ~recall(.x, .y))`.

Comment: Added a missing line `iris_b$Species <- as.factor(iris_b$Species)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what the error message suggests. Convert the data to `factor`, also using `map2_dbl` since `recall` returns a number back.

```
library(tidyverse)

cv_perf_recall  <- cv_bank_prep %>%
           mutate(validate_recall = map2_dbl(validate_actual,validate_predicted,
                  ~caret::recall(factor(.x),factor(.y))))
```